# Proper save/restore of RNG state in boost::random behaving unexpectedly

Tags: boost, random

I have a small test program that attempts to save and restore the state of a random number generator using boost::random, but it is not behaving as the documentation indicates. From the boost docs:

> Classes which model a pseudo-random number generator should also model the Streamable concept, i.e. implement operator<< and operator>>. If so, operator<< writes all current state of the pseudo-random number generator to the given ostream so that operator>> can restore the state at a later time. The state shall be written in a platform-independent manner, but it is assumed that the locales used for writing and reading be the same. The pseudo-random number generator with the restored state and the original at the just-written state shall be equivalent.

As I understand it, if a RNG state is saved and then a number is pulled from it, the state should change. If the state is later restored, this should allow the exact same number to be generated as the generator has been rolled back. I made a test program that examines this, but at first glance it seems like the state is not restored. Consider the code:

```
 unsigned int s = static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0));

//typedef boost::minstd_rand base_generator_type;
typedef boost::mt19937 base_generator_type;
base_generator_type randgen(s);
boost::uniform_01<base_generator_type> getrand(randgen);
//boost::normal_distribution<float> noise(0,1);
//boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type,
//boost::normal_distribution<float> > getrand(randgen, noise);

double numsbefore[2], numsrightafter[2], numsnew[4];

//generate a short sequence, save it, and display
numsbefore[0] = getrand();
numsbefore[1] = getrand();

cout << "First Sequence, before save: " 
     << numsbefore[0] << " "
     << numsbefore[1]  << endl; 

//save the current RNG state to a file using the stream interface
std::ofstream rngfileout("test_rngfile.txt");
rngfileout << randgen;
rngfileout.close();

//generate the next two numbers and display
numsrightafter[0] = getrand();
numsrightafter[1] = getrand();
cout << "Next, right after save: " 
   << numsrightafter[0] << " "
   << numsrightafter[1] << endl;

 //read in the RNG state that was saved, back into the RNG, restoring the state
 //to be such as it was prior to the most recent two calls to randgen()
 std::ifstream rngfilein("test_rngfile.txt", ifstream::in);

 if(!rngfilein.good())
 {
  cout << "Couldn't read from file\n";
  return 0;
 }
rngfilein >> randgen;
rngfilein.close();

//declare and initialize a new variate generator to the newly-restored generator
boost::uniform_01<base_generator_type> getrand2(randgen);
//   boost::variate_generator<base_generator_type, 
//     boost::normal_distribution<float> > getrand2(randgen, noise);

//copy the new variate function into the old one, to allow us to use
//the old one on the restored generator   
getrand = getrand2;

//generate the next sequence
//The first two should be the same as the most recent two called
//The next two should be new random numbers
numsnew[0] = getrand();
numsnew[1] = getrand();
numsnew[2] = getrand();
numsnew[3] = getrand();

cout << "Restored, Next: " 
     << numsnew[0] << " "
     << numsnew[1] << " "
     << numsnew[2] << " "
     << numsnew[3] << endl;
```

The output for a given time seed is:

> First Sequence, before save: 0.970021 0.266862
>   Next, right after save: 0.110485 0.267466 
>   Restored, Next: 0.970021 0.266862 0.110485 0.267466

---

The code's comments illustrate what I think should be happening. Also, some lines include commented code to do the same test with a different generator and different distribution. The same problem occurs for any of those: the next two values taken from the generator randgen after the state has been restored are not the same as the two that are generated immediately after the save, as they should be.

Upon closer inspection (debugging), it appears that calls to the variate generator getrand() do not change the state of the generator `randgen` at all no matter how many times I call getrand() on it, and so when I save it, it remains the same as if it were just created, and thus, when I pull from it again after restoration, it just starts from the beginning.

Shouldn't each call to the generator cause the state to advance? How am I even getting sequences that are not the same numbers if the RNG state never changes? Is the generator I'm viewing/saving not the "real" one, or something?

Also, the assignment operation of `getrand = getrand2` might look sketchy but the = operator is defined for those,and replacing the last 4 calls with `getrand2()` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the generator I'm viewing/saving not the "real" one, or something?

That is indeed the case. The `uniform_01` constructor you're using actually makes a *copy* of the provided engine, rather than taking a reference.

If you're using Boost 1.39 or later, you can use it like this instead:

```
boost::uniform_01<> getrand;
getrand(randgen);
```

If you're stuck on an older Boost and you don't need `getrand` to be copyable, changing `uniform_01`'s type parameter from `base_generator_type` to `base_generator_type&` should also work.